# asp.net lock grid when checkbox selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I have a grid that includes a checkbox control with Autopostback=yes and CheckChanged calling a routine in the vb.net code that updates the record with the checkbox value. When a checkbox is clicked it takes a second or two to run the code and return control back to the web page. I have some users that are clicking several checkboxes one after another so the program is not being called correctly and they are getting a hodgepodge of updated records. For now my solution is for them to wait until the page refreshes before they click the next one. Pretty lamo. Does anyone have any suggestions to work around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little jQuery function to temporarily hide your checkbox immediately after it has been checked.

Maybe extend the code below slightly to display a `<div id="loading">Loading...</div>` or loading .gif image [image] to the user so that they know that your page is being processed and don't get frustrated:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#" + "<%: CheckBox1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).hide()
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much Dennis! Your solution finally got me learning jQuery (which I have wanted to do for some time) and helped me get it to work like I wanted.

When the grid loads all the check boxes show with their values. When one is clicked the jquery below runs and hides them all. I have an OnCheckedChanged event on the asp checkbox control that calls the program and updates the clicked record, and when the grid loads again all the check boxes show with their correct values. Totally cool!

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
            $("input:checkbox").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```